# HTML select element: how to simulate a "onStayTheSame" event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, select

For a select element we have the `onchange` event. I'm looking to trigger a function call if the user clicks on the drop down, but then selects the same current option.

Am wondering if anyone has tried this before, and what a reliable sequence of onclicks, onmouseups etc might look like.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this...

```
var select = document.getElementById('your-element'),
    changed = false;

select.onchange = function() {
    changed = true;
    console.log('Picked something new.');

}

select.onfocus = function() {
    changed = false;
}

select.onblur = function() {
    if (!changed) {
        select.onStayTheSame.call();
    }
    changed = false;
}

select.onStayTheSame = function() {
    console.log('Stayed the same.');
}
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fpZW/).

It has a few issues, but hopefully this is a good start :)

Comment: nice to see it posted on JsFiddle